# How to check what features mail server supports?

Tags: ssl, email-server, tls

just curious if there any tool that I can just give a mail server address/ip to and that would give me all features that mail server supports.

Like:
does it support imap/pop3?
Does it support tls/ssl/ntlm encryption?
etc....

thanks:)

Comment: You seem to be confusing the capabilities with the protocols. There is no definition of what an 'email server' is and no such agreed protocol as 'email' - they are a family of different protocols.

Answer (score 3):

Services can usually be determined by a quick port scan, but this can (and should) trigger any decent IDS into shutting you out of the network completely.

For checking the authentication methods, a simple EHLO should list the relevant details:

```
C:\Users\mark.henderson>telnet enetsxs1 25

220 enetsxs1.com.au Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 9 Feb 2011 15:42:09
+1100
ehlo
250-enetsxs1.com.au Hello [192.168.161.140]
250-SIZE 10485760
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
```

Comment: I see. so basically old good telnet/nmap is the way to go:)

Comment: @Andre - pretty much :)

Comment: While that will give a fair bit of information about the SMTP service it will not tell you anything about other protocols, such as IMAP and POP3, or even if they are implemented. Each protocol will need to be tested separately.

Comment: @John - the port scan will give you a reasonably good idea if the ports are open at least - so that's a start